# Green card surrendered, is it necessary to apply for a new tourist visa?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

During a multiple entry Tourist Visa (B1/B2) period, my wife obtained a Green Card. After about 5 years, she surrendered her Green card at a US Consulate in India.

At this point in time, her multiple entry Tourist Visa (B1/B2) has a validity of about 3 years. The Tourist Visa (B1/B2) was not marked as 'Cancelled'. In this situation, if she wants to travel to the US, is it necessary for her to apply for a new multiple entry Tourist visa (B1/B2) or can she travel using her existing Tourist Visa?

Answer (score 4):

If the visa is not cancelled, there is no reason to apply for a new one. You can still travel to the US on a non-immigrant visa but you should carry your I-407, Record of Abandonment of Lawful Permanent Resident Status:

> Use this form to let us know you are voluntarily abandoning your status as a lawful permanent resident (LPR) of the United States. We will update your records to show you are no longer an LPR.

([Source](https://www.uscis.gov/i-407))

> If you travel to the U.S. on a non-immigrant visa in the future (or on a Visa Waiver Program, if you qualify because of your country or citizenship), present your non-immigrant visa (or just passport if travelling on a Visa Waiver Program) and a copy of the I-407 next time you enter the United States. This will minimize your risk of complications with the immigration officer at port of entry concerning your immigrant versus non-immigrant status.

([Source](https://www.immihelp.com/greencard/abandonment-greencard.html))